# "User control" in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, windows-phone-8, user-controls, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am creating an application using Xamarin.Android with MVVMCross. In Windows Phone I use this simple user control:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Source="{Binding Image1}"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}">
    <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding Image2}"/>
</Grid>
```

In the code behind is some logic and a dependency property. I used this component in many places of my application.Image1, Image2, Title - dependency property. Is it possible to implement user controls in Xamarin.Android? Or in Android by some other method?

An example of what I need:
1. xml file

```
 <LinearLayout>
    <TextView
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       local:MvxBind="Text MyText"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```

2. in code

   ```
       public class MyComponent  
       {
         public string MyText { get;set;}            
       }
   ```
3. in view

   ```
    <MyControl local:MvxBind="MyText DataText"/>
   ```

   property DataText in ViewModel.
   [N28 custom building](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=taBoOenbpiU) - it seems. But it is filled in the code LinearLayot.I also want to use the xml file.

Comment: Custom view? http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: Try looking through the N+1 videos... you will find several "custom control" and "user control" scenarios there - e.g. search for MvxFrameControl

Comment: I edited my question and wrote what I need